# Text area string when populated from database always starts indented

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am populating a text area with a string field, and it always shows indented:

**Rendered HTML:**

[image: Text Area]

**Database row:**

[image: DB row]

**HTML outputting the string:**

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="2" name="comment">
    {{$chosen->comment}}
</textarea>
```

Why is this and how can I resolve it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have a tab inside your textarea. Swap your code to this:

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="2" name="comment">{{$chosen->comment}}</textarea>
```

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/vhcjqvw8/

Comment: I cannot believe that! IDE auto-formatting at its finest. Many thanks @David Jones!

Comment: We have all been there! No worries, glad I could help